# Error connecting to synergy on mac server

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, synergy

I installed synergy.  I ran it on mac OS X mavericks 10.9.4.  When I open synergy on the mac a window pops up quickly and disappears.  Then, I connect from my windows workstation and get an error:

> NOTE: connecting to 'x.y.z.a': x.y.z.a:24800 INFO: crypto mode: cfb
>   ERROR: server refused client with name "pcName" WARNING: failed to
>   connect to server: server refused client with our name

1. How can I tell if synergy is running on Mac OS X?

   - I tried Terminal > netstat -an .  There are 100's of lines.  I see one that says:

```
Local Address:  *.24800
Foreign Address *.*
state:  LISTEN
```

2. What causes this error?

   - I saw a [troubleshooting link](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/trouble.html#problem6) on the synergy site.  I'm running the default configuration on both ends.  "Unknown screen name XXX" (referred to by this error) seems to apply to people doing oddball stuff.
   - I tried to telnet into x.y.z.a 24800 and it appears to have worked.  I see encrypted jibber jabber on the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Mac sure you set the screens names on both server and client to not have any special chars.

Restart software.

On the server click preferences and make sure that the computers shown both have the same screen names. Just double click and change.

Should be all good

Comment: This worked for me on a client with the "." symbol between each word. Nothing complicated with ports or firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the computer name with the Synergy Application open > Synergy Menu > Preferences:

[image]

Note that Synergy must be opened from the [menu bar](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2473).

[image]

Synergy will not display a GUI when opened from the [dock.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2474)

<strike>- Create a computer name that does not contain spaces or dashes
- Copy configuration file located in:</strike>

/var/folders/s9/vvv8y27d6q51rfzcf9d4nvlh0000gn/T/Synergy.xxxYYY

to

/Users/username/Synergy.conf (renamed xxxYYY to conf)

- Modify the aliases section of the Synergy.conf file:

section: aliases 
       newHostname: 
           oldHostName.local 
end

- When launching Synergy server choose "Use existing configuration".  Select the file at

/Users/username/Synergy.conf

Comment: Reinstalling Synergy did not correct the hostname.  Reinstalling with AppTrap also did not fix it.  Running `sudo scutil --set HotsName newHostName` also did not correct Synergy.

Answer (score 0):

I too spend some time in this. The button for this is not that obvious. it looks like a icon rather that a button.
[image]

Use this monitor type icon to add (by dragging) one more monitor to your server setup. DO not use the special character in its name.